# Still returning NULL when default value added

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to replace NULL with a default value of 'NO' but even when I execute it, it still displays NULL when I try to view the data. I've already tried dropping the constraint on the column, but it did not work

```
/*------------------------
use AuntieB
--alter table charity
--  add STORE char(10);
--update charity
--set STORE = 'YES'
--where Name = 'Salvation Army' or Name = 'Mother Wattles' or Name = 'Fresh Start Charity'
alter table charity
    add default 'No' for STORE;
select * from charity
------------------------*/
  CharityID Name                 Address                        City                           State Zip        Phone          ContactID STORE
----------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----- ---------- ------------ ----------- ----------
       1000 St. Francis Home     45875 West. Hill St.           Utica                          MI    48045      586-795-3486        1025 NULL
       1001 Helping Hands        98563 Stadium                  Detriot                        MI    48026      313-978-6589        1030 NULL
       1002 Boy Scouts           1155 E. Long Lake Rd           Troy                           MI    48085      248-253-9596        1036 NULL
       1003 Focus Hope           54362 Grand River              Detroit                        MI    48312      313-478-7895        1041 NULL
       1004 Fresh Start Charity  12569 Gratiot Ave.             Roseville                      MI    48084      555-555-2035        1046 YES       
       1005 St. John Hospital    59652 Shelby Rd.               Shelby Twp.                    MI    48317      586-569-6987        1050 NULL
       1006 Salvation Army       56231 Somewhere Blvd.          Eastpointe                     MI    48021      586-555-1212        1056 YES       
       1007 LA Angels Traders    2468 Halo Park Dr South        Los Angelas                    MI    90234      903-965-3556        2015 NULL
       1008 Purple Heart         28765 Van Dyke                 Sterling Heights               MI    48313      586-732-8723        1061 NULL
       1009 St. Raja Home        45875 West. Hill St.           Utica                          MI    48045      586-795-3486        1062 NULL
       1010 Mother Wattles       4568 Griswold                  Detroit                        MI    48205      313-478-9856        2016 YES       
       1011 Ron McDonald House   649 West Road                  Utica                          MI    48045      586-795-9979        1030 NULL
       1012 St. Jude             262 Danny Thomas Place         Memphis                        MI    38105      800-822-6344        1030 NULL

(13 rows affected)
```

Comment: Hint: `CASE WHEN`

Comment: So what is the question here? The SQL in question have a **very specific** where clause stating which rows to update. Are you confused about what it does? Or are you perhaps confused about what your task is? Please explain clearly which row(s) you expected to change **and why**.

Comment: Please be aware that default values for rows only take effect when *inserting* new rows. Did you think that changing the default would apply this to existing rows perhaps?

Comment: I was completely unaware that these default values only exist when inserting rows, Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191289(v=sql.105).aspx):

> When a DEFAULT definition is added to an existing column in a table, by default, the Database Engine applies the new default only to new rows of data that are added to the table. Existing data that was inserted by using the previous DEFAULT definition is unaffected. However, when you add a new column to an existing table, you can specify that the Database Engine insert the default value (specified by the DEFAULT definition) instead of a null value, into the new column for the existing rows in the table.

So when adding a DEFAULT definition to an existing column, you need to fill the existing rows yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add a new default constraint to an existing column and update exiting NULL values in the same DDL operation. You'll need to explicitly update values NULL values to the desired value afterward.

You can, however, add a new column with a default constraint and apply the default value to all existing rows by specifying the `WITH VALUES` clause:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.charity
    ADD store char(10) NULL
    CONSTRAINT df_charity_STORE DEFAULT 'No'
    WITH VALUES;
```

This method allows you to add a new `NOT NULL` column too.

If you are running Enterprise (or Developer) edition of SQL Server, `WITH VALUES` is a meta-data only operation, which avoids updating every row in the table internally during the operation. The operation physically updates each row in the table in lessor editions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here. You can update all null values like this;

```
update charity
set STORE = 'NO'
where STORE is null
```

or If you want to replace null values only when selecting them, you can use `ISNULL` statement.

```
select ISNULL(STORE,'NO') from charity
```

Also, adding constraint with default value for existing column doesn't update previous data. It sets default value for new coming rows.

Comment: So there is no way of just having 'NO' in place of the null w/o using the update or ISNULL?

Comment: No, you should update them or check null rows when selecting them using ISNULL.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification, I was struggling with this for a bit